# Fail to rename docker image at Azure pipelines

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I try to rename the build image, using this task:

```
steps:
- task: Docker@0
  displayName: 'Run a Docker TAG rename'
  inputs:
    containerregistrytype: 'Container Registry'
    dockerRegistryConnection: 'docker hub'
    action: 'Run a Docker command'
    customCommand: 'tag  azuretp:latest (my docker hub account)/dockerhub:myfirstpush'
```

but fails with the error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe" tag azuretp:latest ***/dockerhub:myfirstpush
Error response from daemon: No such image: azuretp:latest
```

Running locally i am able to rename it, using the command:

```
docker tag trfoutwsrv:dev (my docker hub account)/dockerhub:myfirstpush
```

At Azure Pipeline Services, the image name changes with build. I already try azuretp:{Build.BuildNumber} but that variable doesn't exist at the task run time.

The goal is to rename the image so it can be pushed after to my docker hub repository.
I already split the original task to rename and then push, but now i am stuck on renaming it.

Comment: first of all, it should be `azuretp:$(Build.BuildNumber)`, but since the image `latest` doesnt exist, I doubt that would help

Comment: Rookie error. The name was on the previous task: azuretp:$(Build.BuildNumber)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case the solution was to use `azuretp:$(Build.BuilNumber)`